# Error while implementing WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, saf

I am getting this message when I am calling a WCF service which is hosted on a server and developed on another server

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E063B04A-CB8B-460E-99D0-F7D8FA2FAAA2} 
failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))`
```

Comment: Are you using 3rd party library in WCF?

Comment: From a quick Google search, that GUID appears to be for a Crystal Reports object. You may want to double-check that you have that installed on the server.